# Creating an Equation for my Online Store

Tags: dynamic-programming, programming

I have a site that I am building and I am trying to figure out how much to charge customers. I want to go as low as possible while maintaining a certain profit margin.

Here are the perimeters: I want 10% of every sale to go the company for profit/operating costs. The credit card processor takes 3% + 0.33 (cents) on every transaction.

How do I find how much to increase the products cost and keeping everything balanced?

Example:

> (150 * 1.13) + 0.33 = 169.83 --Retail Price
>
> (169.83 * 0.03) + 0.33 = 5.4249 --Credit Card Process Fee
>
> (168.83 * 0.1) = 16.983 --10% Profit
>
> 169.83 - (5.4249 + 16.983) = 147.4221 --Ammount Left After Costs
>
> 147.4221 < 150
>
> 13% increase is not enough to meet profit margin.

I was able to find an exact percentage to increase the original cost when x = 150, which is 15.1954023%, but I can't manually do this for every product as I could have hundreds/thousands with many different pricing options.

Thanks in advance. Any help is useful, even if you tell me it's not possible at all (at least then I will know).

Comment: If $S$ is sale price and $P$ is a product cost to you, then $S=1.13 \cdot P +0.33$

Comment: I updated the example (for clarity), but what I was trying to say is that a flat 13% + 0.33 is not enough to meet my profit margins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try reasoning backwards. Let $P$ be the original product price and $S$ the desired sale price. Then:

- We start with the price of $S$ that you charge your customers;
- $10\%$ of $S$, i.e. $0.1S$, goes to your profits and operational costs;
- $3\%$ of $S$ plus another $0.33$ (cents), i.e. $0.03S+0.33$, goes to the credit card company.

Since you want to keep your price as low as possible, after taking away these expenses you should end up with original product price:
$$S-0.1S-(0.03S+0.33)=P.$$

Solving this equation for $S$ we find that
$$0.87S-0.33=P \implies S=\frac{P+0.33}{0.87}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I don't know why I couldn't figure this out on my own. Either way, you are a life saver.